# Single quotes in LIKE into JDBC prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm implementing a search using a keyword over database rows. 
I have to execute this query using a JDBC prepared statement.

```
SELECT id, name, ci FROM clients WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE '%keyword%'
```

What i tried was:

```
ps = getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT id, 
                                              name, 
                                              ci 
                                       FROM clientes 
                                       WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE '%?%'");
```

If i write this, the system find rows that have the ? symbol at start or end. 
And obviously the below statement fails saying that the query doesn't have an argument to pass to.

```
ps.setString(1, keyword);
```

Same way with:

```
SELECT id, nombre, ci FROM clientes WHERE LOWER(nombre) LIKE %?%
```

Any help is very appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try SQL text with a form like this:

```
... LIKE CONCAT('%', ? , '%')
```

Comment: I'll take this as correct answer because it was the approach that i follow. It was faster and works fine, simpler than surround the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Your  prepared statement should be

```
SELECT id, name, ci FROM clients WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE ?
```

then you can set the parameter to `%keyword%`.